# I'm trying to print out 5 random 3 letter strings but every time i try it tells me the int type has no len

Tags: python

I want to print out a set of 5 random responses from this list but every time I try I get the error message saying that type int has no len.

I've tried everything I can think of but I'm only a student and don't really know what I'm doing.

```
  import random

  num = random.randrange(1,6)

  endings = {
    1: "ing",
    2: "end",
    3: "axe",
    4: "gex",
    5: "goh",
  }

  #print (endings.get(num))

  stu_num = int(input("how many students will there be? "))

  #print(random.choice(endings))

  for x in range (stu_num):
    print (len(random.choice(endings)))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I dont understand the error you say, it just doesn't hapen so is this the exact and entire code you are trying to run, also could you share the entire error message?

Comment: First of all this is not a list but a dictionary. Second you say you want 5 random responses from your "list" but you are printing the length of the values which will always be three from you example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len(endings)` is 5, because it's a dictionary and has many entries.

`random.choice(...)` will generate a random number between 0 and the length of the dictionary. It will then try to access the dictionary with that number. If there is a result, you'll get the item of the dictionary back.

The item might be "ing", so the length of that item is 3 (as for all other items as well).

However, note that your dictionary does not have numbers from 0 to 4, instead it has numbers from 1 to 5. That means:

1. if the dictionary is accessed with a value of 0, it will crash due to a KeyError, because there is no definition like `0: "abc"`
2. Item number 5 will never be picked.

What you possibly want:

- `list(endings.values())`: convert the values into a list with indexes from 0 to 4, so that all items could be picked
- you don't want to print the length of the student names (3), but their name instead
- also, if you want to pick 5 students, you don't want to pick the same student twice. That means you need to remove the chosen student from the dictionary or list.

Suggested code:

```
# ...
students = list(endings.values())
for x in range(stu_num):
    picked = random.choice(students)
    students.remove(picked)
    print(picked)
```